# Why is file_get_contents() not reading certain data from file CSV file

Tags: php

I have a PHP v5.6 script that reads an uploaded CSV file containing a few rows and columns of plaintext, and one of the cells contains JavaScript code.  Here is the output from my Ubuntu 18.04 bash shell when I do `cat test.csv`...

```
First Name,Last Name
Jane,Doe
John,<script>alert(‘test’);</script>
```

In my PHP script, the uploaded file is read directly from the superglobal array: `$csv = $_FILES["Uploaded_File"]["tmp_name"]`.

If I do `$contents = strip_tags(file_get_contents($csv));`, then the contents of the JS text cell is read, along with all the other plaintext cells:  `var_dump($contents)` displays `string(55) "First Name,Last Name Jane,Doe John,alert(‘test’); "`

But if I do `$contents2 = file_get_contents($csv);`, then all the data in the CSV is read, EXCEPT for the JS text cell: `var_dump($contents2)` displays `string(72) "First Name,Last Name Jane,Doe John, "`

Why is `$contents2 = file_get_contents($csv);` not showing the JS text cell?

Why is `var_dump($contents2)` showing `string(72)` when the actual string has more bytes than what is being displayed?

Here is a snippet of the script:...

```
$csv = $_FILES["Uploaded_File"]["tmp_name"];

$contents = strip_tags(file_get_contents($_FILES["Uploaded_File"]["tmp_name"]));
echo __FILE__." = ".__LINE__." = ";var_dump($contents);echo "<hr />";

$contents2 = file_get_contents($_FILES["Uploaded_File"]["tmp_name"]);
echo __FILE__." = ".__LINE__." = ";var_dump($contents2);echo "<hr />";
```

I read the PHP manual about `file_get_contents()`, but there is no mention about tags not being allowed in the file that is being read from (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).  There is an option to use a `context`, but I do not recognize any option that would solve this.

Maybe it is a `php.ini` setting...? :/

Comment: I would think this is something outside of that code causing your issue. You should post your entire relevant code so we can see exactly how you are using this.

Comment: @JohnConde I edited my question to include more relevant code.

Comment: `but there is no mention about tags not being allowed in the file` they are allowed, but if you echo them `<script>alert(‘test’);</script>` to a HTML page they become part of the source code ... which you will not see.  try `htmlentities($contents2)`  instead of `var_dump($contents2)`, also don't roll your own `fgetcsv` function, PHP has stuff that works really well for reading CSV files.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks!  Your comment solved the problem.   Also, a related issue that was adding to my confusion was the echoed JS was producing JS syntax errors in `[F12]` of the displayed web page because the apostrophes were `Non-ASCII U+2018` (‘) and `Non-ASCII U+2019` (’) instead of `ASCII U+27` ('), i.e., `<script>alert(‘test’);</script>` instead of `<script>alert('test');</script>`.

Comment: kool, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view the result in a browser, you should output the content as plain text and also with a appropriate charset because the quote marks around `test` (or `Yikes`) are not ASCII characters.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=gb18030');
var_dump($contents2);
```